# Trying to create an autofollow javascript for Quora

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, buttonclick, quora

I am trying to create an autofollow button for Quora website so that I can follow all the poeple I run while being on the following page of the profile i like.

Now, I have tried the following codes inside 'Custom JavaScript for websites' - a Google Chrome extension but nothing has worked so far.

Code 1:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    $(document).ready(function(){ 
    $('.follow_button').trigger('click'); 
   });
</script>
```

Code 2:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
window.location.href = $('.follow_button with_count').attr('href');
});
</script>
```

As both the above codes have failed to click on the follow button that appears, what shall I do to achieve the desired result?

Comment: You say the follow button appears (I've never used Quora)? You probably have to delegate the `click` higher up the dom if it's appearing after the page has loaded.

Answer (score -1):

Try this one:

```
$('.Profile.ActionBar .follow_button').click()
```

Comment: This also did not work sir. I am using the extension Custom Javascript for Websites for Google to implement the javascript - is that the problem